# ReactNative Image component - max image size

Tags: image, react-native, size

Is there a resolution limit or image file limit on the Image component and what is it? Or is it caused by limits of the device?
I tried to display an image of size 3992x2992, file size 3.24MB in my app, but failed. I tried compressing the file further down to 300kB, but still failed.

`<Image
    style = {{width: 200, height: 100}}
    source = {require('./res/img/20160731175405-c7bf89df.jpg')}>
</Image>`

ReactNative: 0.42
Device: Galaxy SII

Comment: Could you share more detail about how it failed?

Comment: @milkersarac, thanks. the image is not display at all. If I add the onError callback at the Image component, then it is called sometime after render(), but the nativeEvent received at onError is an empty object, there is no error mesage.

Comment: I see. I think independent from the image size you are having an issue about showing any image, jpg or png right? Does it work on the Android emulator? You might need to bundle your project before running it on the actual device.

Comment: @milkersarac, yes, it runs correctly on emulator. later till try to do release build run on device. for now, will use onError callback to handle failure cases. thanks.

Comment: Did anyone solve this problem I have the same issue also .